Doubt in Simplex method, as why the cost for a slack variable is being taken, even though it shows the unused capacity.
Given set of linear equations, of an augmented (added slack variables, for the maximization problem) LPP, with the form : $AX=B,$ with the matrix $B$ showing the resource constraints, the matrix $A$ showing the coefficients (resource used/unit of the variable).
In the attached screenshot, there is a variant of Simplex's tabular method used, that uses the notations:

$z$ for the objective function. 
$j$ for the number of variables, i.e. both the $n$ decision variables, and $m$ slack variables, with one corresponding to each of the $m$ structural constraints. 
$i$ for the number of variables in the basis, i.e. $i\leq m.$
$C_j$ for the profit/unit of the decision variables, which is given by the coefficient of the corresponding decision variable, in the objective function. The value is $=0,$ for the value of $j>n.$ 
$Z_j$ is the column-wise loss/cost-of-replacing per unit of the given $j$-th variable (both the decision, and the slack variable). It is given by the summation $\sum X_{ij}c_i,$ where $c_i$ is the entry for the cost of the variable for the $i-$th, while $X_{ij}$ is the coefficient, in the $j$-th variable column.
$b$ for the single column matrix of the basic variables, and $C_b$ for the cost of basic variables.
$Z=\sum_{i=1}^{i=m} C_i b_i$ as the cumulative cost, for all the basic variables, & has no link with $Z_j.$
It is given by the summation of the product of the $i$-th basic variable ($b_i$) with its corresponding value in $C_i.$  Initially, only the slack variables lie in the basis, while the entering decision variables, in the later steps, would have its replacement-value-loss as the entry in $C_i.$ 
Also, the value of $C_i$ is the same as that given by the objective function, i.e. $C_j.$ Only the range of the subscript $i$ is limited by the number of basic variables being $\leq m,$ while the range of the subscript $j$ being limited by $n+m.$

For the below augmented LPP:
Maximize $z = 500x_1 + 450x_2,$
subject to the constraints:
$C1: 6x_1 + 5x_2 + x_3(=s_1)= 60,$
$C2: x_1+2x_2 + x_4(=s_2)= 15,$
$C3: x_1+ x_5(=s_3)= 8,$
and $C4: x_1\geq 0, C5: x_2\geq 0, C6: x_3(=s_1)\geq 0, C7: x_4(=s_2)\geq 0, C8: x_5(=s_3)\geq 0.$
Have the below initial tableau:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} = \text{ Cost of i-th B.V., } i\leq m & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
s_1  & 0  & 60 & 6 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 10\\ \hline
s_2  & 0  & 15 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 15\\ \hline
s_3  & 0  & 8 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 8 \\ \hline
Z=0   & & Z_j & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \\ \hline
& & C_j & 500 & 450 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\ \hline
& & C_j - Z_j & 500 & 450 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
The initial tableau has the initial BFS: $(0,0,60,15,8),$ and need find the adjacent BFS. For that need find the maximum value of the coefficient (of the decision variable) in the objective function $z.$
So, the entering variable, in basis, is $x_1,$ and by the minimum ratio, $s_3$ is the leaving variable.
The new BFS is: $(8,0,12,7,0),$ which is shown in the below first (after, the initial tableau) tableau.
For the purpose of new tableau, need do pivoting of the other rows, using the third row. The pivot is the coefficient $a_{31}.$ The third row is divided by it. 
Need eliminate the coefficient of $x_1$ from all other rows.
For the first row, subtract by the terms obtained by multiplying $\frac{a_{11}}{a_{31}},$ to the coefficients of the third row; to get the corresponding new coefficients, in the first row.
Similarly, for the second row, need subtract the terms obtained by multiplying by $\frac{a_{21}}{a_{31}},$ to the coefficients of the third row; to get the corresponding coefficients, in the second row.
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} = \text{ Cost of i-th B.V., } i\leq m & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
s_1  & 0  & 12 (60-8*6) & 0(6-6*1) & 5 & 1 & 0 & -6(0-6*1) & 12/5\\ \hline
s_2  & 0  & 7 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & -1(0-1*1) & 7/2\\ \hline
x_1  & 500  & 8 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \\ \hline
Z=4000 (=500*8) & & Z_j & 500 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 500 &   \\ \hline
& & C_j & 500 & 450 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
& & C_j - Z_j & 0 & 450 & 0 & 0 &  -500 & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
The maximum coefficient in objective function, is of $x_2,$ and the leaving variable is given by the minimum ratio of: $12/5,$ i.e. $s_1$ is the leaving variable.
My doubt lies in the logic for the multiplication of $a_{35}=1$ with the value of $C_3= 500,$ as $a_{35}$ is a slack variable, and am unable to comprehend why its cost is found, just like a decision variable.
Also, the slack variable represents the idle/non-utilised capacity/resources out of the one available.
Say, coefficient of $s_3$ represents the idle units of the resource, whose limit is $8$ units.
Hence, the logic for multiplying the resource cost (due to replacement cost, for the current B.V. $x_1$) with the slack variable coefficient (here, of $s_3$) is unclear.
Note: The problem was given in a slide, whose screenshot is attached herewith. 

When entering $x_1$, you need to pivot to put a zero in column $C_j-Z_j$. So you need to substract 500 times row $3$ to the row $6$, giving $500$ in row $C_j-Z_j$, columns $s_3$, and so $-500$ in column $Z_j$

@caduk Sorry, need more elaboration, as have learnt that $C_j$ for a slack variable is always $\leq 0.$

Well, $C_j = 0$ for $s_3$, where is the problem?

@caduk The doubt is in the logic for multiplying slack variable coefficient (here, of $s_3$) with replacement cost of $x_1,$ i.e. $500.$

Now that $x_1$ has entered the basis, we want the objective to not depend on $x_1$ but on $s_3$. Using the equation $x_1+s_3 = 8$, we can rewrite the objective function as $500(8-s_3)+450 x_2 = 4000 -500s_3+450x_2$. Intuitively, it makes sense: if we augment $s_3$, we will need to lower $x_1$, which will makes us lose $500$ in the objective function.

@caduk So, the role of objective function is limited to find using the  maximum value of $Z_j - C_j,$ the entering variable  among the non-basic decision variables. And, it is a must to find the next adjacent BFS, by rewriting in terms of the out-going slack variable. But, it would be interesting to observe this rewriting, for a LPP, with the optimal point reached after at least $3-4 $ edges, after the initial point.


In the first iteration, we were considering whether to move to the right or move up. Upon examining each direction, we decide to move to the right.
We decide to move from $(0,0)$ to $(0,8)$, each unit of increment of $x_1$ would gain us $500$.
Now, at the second iteration, we were considering whether to increment $s_1$ or increment $x_2$. The cost of incrementing $s_1$ by one unit is equal to the cost of decreasing $x_1$ by one unit, each movement reduces $500$, and hence we move upward. Note that increasing a unit of slack variable $s_3$ here corresponds to reducing a unit of $x_1$.

Thanks, can see that the left variables are : $s_1, x_2,$ hence choice is left between them for entering the basis.

Request if some elaboration is possible of the role of the objective function, in determining the next d.v.; i.e. the substitution, in the objective function: $z$ in terms of the newly entered d.v., in the basis. For that an interesting case can occur only with $\gt 3$ d.v, with constraints s.t. need traverse $n$ ($=$# of d.v.) of shared edges (formed by the intersection of constraints). Say, for the above, have the BFS ($(8,0,12,7,0)$) formed by the intersection of $C3, C4.$ And, the next BFS ($(8,12/5, 0, 11/5, 0$) formed by the intersection of $C1, C3.$

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4059651/306553 interpretation of reduced cost.
